# Refine Results with dropdown box

Tags: php

I would like to refine the results of mysql query using dropdown boxes... live site is here:
http://www.halfwayenterprises.com/search/tyrell.php

```
     <form name="doublecombo" action="" method="POST">

    <label for="status">Status:</label>

<label for="current">
<input class="radio_style" id="current" checked="checked" name="status" type="radio" value="current">
Current
</label>

<label for="obsolete">
<input class="radio_style" id="obsolete" name="status" type="radio" value="obsolete">
Obsolete
</label>

<label for="both">
<input class="radio_style" id="both" name="status" type="radio" value="both">
ALL
</label>

<br /><br />




<select name="category" size="1" onChange="redirect(this.options.selectedIndex)">
<option value="null">Category</option>
<option value="asset management">Asset Management</option>
<option value="budget">Budget/Finance</option>
<option value="central office">Central Office</option>
<option value="disposal">Disposal</option>
</select>





<select name="subcategory">
<option value="null">Sub-Category</option>
<option value="Portfolio">Portfolio</option>
<option value="Pricing">Pricing</option>
<option value="Valuation">Valuation</option>

<option value="Disposal">Disposal</option>





</select>
<input name="submitted" type="submit" value="GO">

<br />









Seach for: <input type="text" name="find" /> in 
<Select NAME="field">
<Option id="title" VALUE="title">Title</option>
<Option id="poc" VALUE="poc">POC</option>
<Option id="purpose" VALUE="purpose">Purpose</option>

</Select>

<input type="hidden" name="searching" value="yes" />





<input name="submitted" type="submit" value="GO">

</form>


<select name="filter1">
<option value="az">Sort by A-Z</option>
<option value="date">Sort by Date</option>
</select>

<select name="filter2">
<option value="office">Sort by Office</option>
<option value="p">P</option>
<option value="pt">PT</option>
<option value="pf">PF</option>
</select>

<select name="filter3">
<option value="mandatory">Mandatory</option>
<option value="nonmandatory">Non-Mandatory</option>
<option value="combined">Combined</option>
</select>


</form>





</p>

<script>
<!--

/*
Double Combo Script Credit
By JavaScript Kit (www.javascriptkit.com)
Over 200+ free JavaScripts here!
*/

var groups=document.doublecombo.category.options.length
var group=new Array(groups)
for (i=0; i<groups; i++)
group[i]=new Array()

group[0][0]=new Option("Sub Category")


group[1][0]=new Option("Portfolio")
group[1][1]=new Option("Pricing")
group[1][2]=new Option("Valuation")

group[3][0]=new Option("Central Office")
group[4][0]=new Option("Disposal")

var temp=document.doublecombo.subcategory

function redirect(x){
for (m=temp.options.length-1;m>0;m--)
temp.options[m]=null
for (i=0;i<group[x].length;i++){
temp.options[i]=new Option(group[x][i].text,group[x][i].value)
}
temp.options[0].selected=true
}

function go(){
location=temp.options[temp.selectedIndex].value
}
//-->
</script>

<?



mysql_connect("localhost", "name", "pasword") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("db") or die(mysql_error()); 

if(isset($_POST["submitted"])){

$status = $_POST['status'];


$category = $_POST['category'];
$subcategory = $_POST['subcategory'];





echo '<div class="status_div">';

if($status=='current')

{
echo "<h2>Results</h2><p>";

$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM material WHERE status='$status' AND category='$category' AND subcategory='$subcategory' ORDER BY `documentid` ASC");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {


echo '<div class="current">';



echo $row ['documentid'].' - '.$row['category'].' - '.$row['title'].' - '.$row['status'];

echo '</div>';

echo '<br>';


}

} if ($status=='obsolete')


{
echo "<h2>Results</h2><p>";
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM material WHERE status='$status' AND category='$category' ORDER BY `documentid` ASC ");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {



echo $row ['documentid'].' - '.$row['category'].' - '.$row['title'].' - '.$row['status'];



echo '<br>';


} 




} if ($status=='both')  

{

echo "<h2>Results</h2><p>";
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM material WHERE status1='both' AND category='$category' ORDER BY `documentid` ASC");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
echo '<div class="">';



echo $row ['documentid'].' - '.$row['category'].' - '.$row['title'].' - '.$row['status'];

echo '</div>';

echo '<br>';

} 

}








echo '</div>';

}















$field = @$_POST['field'] ;
$find = @$_POST['find'] ;
$searching = @$_POST['searching'] ;
$status = $_POST['status'];

//This is only displayed if they have submitted the form 
if ($searching =="yes") 
{ 
echo "<h2></h2><p>"; 


//If they did not enter a search term we give them an error 
if ($find == "") 
{ 

echo "<a href='tyrell.htm'>Return</a>";
exit; 
} 


// We preform a bit of filtering 
$find = strtoupper($find); 
$find = strip_tags($find); 
$find = trim ($find); 

//Now we search for our search term, in the field the user specified 


if($status=='current'){

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM material WHERE status='$status' AND lower($field) LIKE'%$find%' LIMIT 0,30");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {

echo '<div class="current">';

echo $row ['documentid'].' - '.$row['category'].' - '.$row['title'].' - '.$row['status'];

echo '</div>';

echo '<br>';

}




}

if ($status=='obsolete'){

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM material WHERE status='$status' AND lower($field) LIKE'%$find%' LIMIT 0,30");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {

echo '<div class="obsolete">';

echo $row ['documentid'].' - '.$row['category'].' - '.$row['title'].' - '.$row['status'];

echo '</div>';

echo '<br>';

} 




} if ($status=='both'){

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM material WHERE status1='both' AND lower($field) LIKE'%$find%' LIMIT 0,30");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {

echo '<div class="">';

echo $row ['documentid'].' - '.$row['category'].' - '.$row['title'].' - '.$row['status'];

echo '</div>';

echo '<br>';

} 

}









//This counts the number or results - and if there wasn't any it gives them a little message explaining that 
$anymatches=mysql_num_rows($data); 
if ($anymatches == 0) 
{ 
echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query<br><br>"; 
} 

//And we remind them what they searched for 
echo "<b>Searched For:</b> " .$find; 
} 


?>

<p align="center"><font face="arial" size="-2">This free script provided by</font><br>
<font face="arial, helvetica" size="-2"><a href="http://javascriptkit.com">JavaScript
Kit</a></font></p>'
</body>
</html>
```

I have can't think of how to use the drop downs without having a submit button

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to manipulate the content of the dropdown list. All you need is to do is bind the click even on the radio button and when one of them gets clicked, use an Ajax call to retrieve the information from your SQL database and modify the content of your selectbox.

*EDIT*

Here's some code you can add to your page:

```
$('form[name=doublecombo] input').change(function() {

    $('form[name=doublecombo]').submit();
});
```

Note that `change` might not work. If it doesn't, try using `click` instead.

Comment: Am having problems attempting to "bind" the dropdown to call the info from the database

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you need...
Use jquery to submit form on you page.

Something like this...

```
$("submitted").click(function() {

    var url = "file.php";

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("doublecombo").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               // populate box or div with your result
           }
         });

    return false; // avoid reload.
});
```

//PHP part

```
   if($_POST['someField']){

    $result = //Do query and staff and return any type of resposne you will handle in ajax success

    echo $result;
    exit;

}
```

Comment: I tried..but due to me being a novice...couldn't implement that code.

Comment: I've played and played..any more help...and i would be very grateful...lol

Comment: You cant send form params to php, or you dont know how to return some data from php ( over ajax ) and populate some html elements with result?